# Consumo de memória e CPU durante um ataque de negação de serviço.Como entender as estatísticas?

Tags: segurança, gerenciamento-de-memória, cpu

A seguinte linha estava no crontab do Ubuntu:

```
  */2   *       *       *       *       echo -e "`date`\n\n`free` \n\n`vmstat`\n" >> /home/hacker/free_vmstat_output.txt
```

Extrai do arquivo free_vmstat_output.txt dois horários que me interessam analisar:

```
-e  Mon Apr 10 08:12:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1271608     143388    1128220       4884      15052      53916
-/+ buffers/cache:      74420    1197188
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 1128220  15052  53916    0    0    38    23   53   87  1  0 99  0  0




-e  Mon Apr 10 09:51:01 -03 2017 

              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1271608     340384     931224       8980      34348     212528
-/+ buffers/cache:      93508    1178100
Swap:       496636          0     496636 

 procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 930248  34348 212528    0    0    23   108 1635  685  1  6 93  0  0
```

Pesquisei mas não consegui entender a parte da CPU. O que são as siglas cs us sy id wa st que aparecem na parte da CPU?

Como comparar o uso de CPU e memória nestes dois momentos distintos? Um dos momentos é antes de um ataque e o outro durante um ataque de negação de serviço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá, seguem as informações que consegui a respeito, espero que te ajude.

Bom, o "cs" que você citou faz parte da área de System e não da CPU. A área correspondente a CPU vai do "us" até "st".

cs - Contabiliza as mudanças de contexto do processador por segundo.

Os valores da área da CPU são porcentagens de uso da unidade de processamento, somados devem correspondem a 100% do uso da unidade.

Nas suas coletas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se somar os valores da área de CPU das suas coletas, o resultado será sempre 100:

1ª coleta:

us  sy  id  wa  st

1 + 0 + 99 + 0 + 0 = 100

2ª coleta:

us  sy  id  wa  st

1 + 6 + 93 + 0 + 0 = 100

Significados das siglas:

us - User Time, tempo da CPU dedicados aos códigos que não são do kernel.

sy - System Time, tempo da CPU dedicados do kernel do sistema.

id - Idle Time, tempo ocioso do sistema.

wa - Waiting for IO, Tempo de espera IO.

st - Stolen Time, Tempo roubado de uma máquina virtual.

Bom, sei que não é muito, mas é basicamente o que está no manual da ferramenta. Espero ter te ajudado

Comment: neste caso, só precisaria olhar o id, certo? Durante o ataque, espera-se que o id diminua, correto? Obrigado!

Comment: A redução do "id" é um indício de que o servidor está dedicando mais tempo ao processo de alguma coisa, o que vai te dizer se é algo relacionado ao kernel ou a outras aplicações é o campo "sy" e o "us".
Mas antes de tirar qualquer conclusão, você tem que identificar qual é o tipo de ataque que está sofrendo.
É um ataque de negação de serviço?
Se sim. Qual tipo de ataque?
De exaustão de hardware, um ataque focado na camada de aplicação ou é um ataque volumétrico?
Identificando isso, você vai ter mais segurança para monitorar o ataque e não confundi-lo com acessos legítimos.

Comment: É um laboratorio que montei com ataque DDos slowloris! Ele vai "gastar" pouca CPU!

Comment: É, esse script faz a abertura de conexões com o servidor em períodos específicos, em rajada. Como ele faz a abertura parcial da conexão no servidor web e não fecha, é provável que o aumento no consumo de memória seja mais notável que o aumento no consumo do processador.
Um outra coisa que você poderia monitorar para identificar esse ataque é o número de conexões simultâneas ao servidor.